Is there a way to query Power Apps data from Copilot Studio?
I'm trying to build a simple copilot that answers questions and can perform aggregations on my data.
I read that Copilot Studio doesn't handle aggregations well. So I built a Power Apps application, added Copilot integration to it based off my Copilot studio bot, then tested the app and received accurate results from the integrated Copilot.
However, when querying my bot from within Copilot Studio, it's as if it cannot see my data. However, it works fine in Power Apps. I'm using manual authentication.
Is there a way to expose my Power Apps data to a copilot studio bot so that I can query the data directly from Copilot studio?
Or am I going about this the wrong way?

I would recommend using the GPT Builder as it allowed you to customize the input stream, has access to dataverse and can provide a lot of insights including aggregation. To do so, you can use power automate flows to conduct analysis. however, you will need a placeholder to hold and display this information.
